# Scala: How to prevent Jackson from deserialization with null

Tags: scala, jackson, deserialization, jackson-module-scala

Say I have a case case such as:

`case class Stuff(name:String,stuffs:List[String] = List.empty)`

How can I prevent jackson from deserialization the json

```
{
  "name":"Alex" 
}
```

With

```
Stuff("Alex",null)
```

I would prefer it to be constructed with

```
Stuff("Alex")
```

Is there a way to configure Jackson to work in this way? or do I have to define other constructors. e.g. with missing `stuffs`

Answer (score 0):

The same problem.

1. You can write your own de-serializer
2. What version are you using: java or scala (json4s)? If java you may try the second one
3. As ugly solution you may wrap stuffs in option, as I know jackson handles options fine.